# How to use variable from an If-Else statement inside Try-Catch (Java)

Tags: java, if-statement, try-catch

How to use a variable from an if-else statement inside Try-Catch in Java?

```
String value1 = "sample"; 
String value2 = "sample";
int a=0;

try 
{

    if(value2.equals(value1))
    {
        a = 1;
    }
     int b = a;

catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Update Error!");
}
```

The `a` in `int b = a;` has an error that says "Variable might not have been initialized". How do I use that variable?

Comment: Either add `else { a = <something>}` to `if`, or initialize `a` at its declaration, like `int a = <something>`.

Comment: None of the comments helped.

Comment: *None of the comments helped* maybe because you did not explain what value you want `a` to have when the condition `value2.equals(value1)` is `false`.

Comment: Your question is not clear. I think you lack some theories regarding exceptions. Integer's default value is 0. BTW equals method does not throw an exception.

Comment: Have you defined the value of your variable as written in the code? like you have written `int a=0;` in your code but as per given error it looks like that you wrote `int a;` in the code. Please recheck this thing.

Comment: You have not copied the code correctly, try closing braces `}` is missing in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you initialize your variable like GMachado said, you don't get the error, which passes the value from 'a' to 'b' inside your try. You also have a syntax error in your code, there's a bracket missing just before the catch.

```
String value1 = "sample"; 
String value2 = "sample";
int a=0;
try 
{
    if(value2.equals(value1))
    {
        a = 1;
    }
     int b = a;
} // Here!!
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Update Error!");
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you only declared it in the line `int a;` but never initialized with a value, besides inside the `if(value2.equals(value1))` block. But because this code inside the if block can't be sure to run, `a` might not get initialized to pass to b. You could initialize a with 0 when you declare (or assign a value later):

```
int a = 0;
```

Comment: you're right, this doesn't pass the value to b, which doesn't really solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign some default value to int variable `a`.

```
String value1 = "sample"; 
String value2 = "sample";
int a = 0;

try 
{
    if(value2.equals(value1))
    {
        a = 1;
    }
    int b = a;

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Update Error!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are somethings that are thrown when something goes wrong. You cannot simply expect to generate an exception. 
There are a lot of exceptions in Java. They all inherit from exception class. IE: ArrayOutOfBoundException, FileNotFoundException,...

You can use the throw function to throw an exception.

Lines of code that are prone to throw an exception must be surrounded by try/catch. This does not mean that everything should be within the try curly braces. The rule is that whenever an reception is thrown, the remaining lines under try body is ignored because the JVM is looking for a catch.